# Convert strange date format to standard date format

Tags: python, mysql, date, format

In Sweden we sometimes use a strange date format, for example New Year is the 31/12. If I have this format as a string ,which can be any date between 1/1 and 31/12, and if we assume that it is this year, how do I get into a standard date format using Python (format as 2012-01-01 and 2012-12-31) that can be sore in be stored as a date in a mySQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply split the two values, map them to integers and update a `datetime.date()` instance:

```
import datetime
day, month = map(int, yourvalue.split('/'))
adate = datetime.date.today().replace(month=month, day=day)
```

By using `datetime.date.today()` we get the current year.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> somevalue = '31/12'
>>> day, month = map(int, somevalue.split('/'))
>>> datetime.date.today().replace(month=month, day=day)
datetime.date(2012, 12, 31)
>>> someothervalue = '1/1'
>>> day, month = map(int, someothervalue.split('/'))
>>> datetime.date.today().replace(month=month, day=day)
datetime.date(2012, 1, 1)
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`datetime.strptime()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse these dates, but you'll have to manually correct the year afterwards (it'll use 1900 as the default if no year is being parsed):

```
adate = datetime.datetime.strptime(yourvalue, '%d/%m').date()
adate = adate.replace(year=datetime.date.today().year)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing strange about this format :)

You can use the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('31/12', '%d/%m').date().replace(year=2012)
print d

>> datetime.date(2012, 12, 31)
```